# How can check Bookings related to specific saloon in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

How can a saloon check the booking like how many people reserve the time slot for different service. When i click on check booking button is show the error

```
 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'saloon'
```

Model.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
   saloon = models.ForeignKey(SaloonRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   service = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   time = models.TimeField()
   date = models.DateField()

class SignUp(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   saloon = models.ForeignKey(SaloonRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()
```

View.py

```
class SaloonCheckBooking(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'saloonCheck.html'

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       checkBooking = Booking.objects.get(saloon_id=self.request.saloon.id)
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'checkBooking': checkBooking})
```

Comment: How do you pass the salloon to the view? Through a URL parameter?

Comment: i am not passing saloon id though url

Comment: well you somehow need to pass the salloon in the request, through the URL, through the querystring, or if the salloon is unique per user. If there is no way to pass the salloon (id), then you can not render it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, a  'WSGIRequest' (aka request) object has no attribute 'saloon'.

It shall be something like

```
checkBooking = Booking.objects.filter(saloon_id=self.request.user.saloon.id)
```

if the user has that attribute.

Edit: Based on SignUp Model

```
 saloons = SignUp.objects.filter(user=request.user)   
 for saloon in saloons:
      checkBooking = Booking.objects.get(saloon_id=saloon.id)
```

Comment: user have no attribute saloon

Comment: then where is the saloon :D

Comment: saloon is the foreign key off booking and user basically is customer id who reserve the slot and i am not passing the saloon id in url

Comment: i am trying to get the information of user who reserve the slot and which service he/she want

Comment: Is the user, an employee,  an owner or a customer?

Comment: He is an employee.when an employee login he/she check which customer reserve the seat

Comment: Then how do you know which saloon does he belongs to?

Comment: I update my question the SignUp basically is an employee table which is link with saloon foreign key

Comment: Check Updated Answer

Comment: Booking matching query does not exist.

Comment: should be filter() not get()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288313/how-can-save-encrypted-data-in-db-using-django